# disable enter key on page, but notin textarea

Tags: javascript

When i press ENTER key the page disappears. So i am disabling the enter key for the form. But If i am in Textarea, I want to enable enter key for new line. NOT A JQUERY SOLUTION PLEASE.

```
 function stopRKey(evt){

        var evt = (evt) ? evt : ((event) ? event : null);
        var node = (evt.target) ? evt.target : ((evt.srcElement) ? 
         evt.srcElement : null);
        if ((evt.keyCode == 13) && (node.type=="text")) {
            return false;
        }
        else if((evt.keyCode==13) && (node.type=="checkbox")){
            return false;
        }

        else if((evt.keyCode==13) && (node.type=="table")){
           return false;
        }
        else if((evt.keyCode==13) && (node.type=="file")){
           return false;
        }
        else if((evt.keyCode==13) && (node.type=="paragraph")){
           return false;
        }
        else if((evt.keyCode==13) && (node.type=="textarea")){
           return false;
        }
        else if((evt.keyCode==13) && (node.type=="list")){
           return false;
        }
        else if((evt.keyCode==13) && (node.type=="choice")){
           return false;
        }

        else if((evt.keyCode==13) && (node.type=="date")){
           return false;
        }
        else if((evt.keyCode==13) && (node.type=="ip_cidr")){
            return false;
        }
        else {
           return true;
        }
 };
   document.onkeypress = stopRKey;
```

Comment: Why do you keep "if((evt.keyCode==13) && (node.type=="textarea")){ return false; }" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.activeElement` gives you the currently focused Element.

```js
function stopRKey(ev){
  if (ev.which == 13){ // which normalizes charCode and keyCode
    var e  = document.activeElement;
    if (e.type == "textarea") return true; // this can also be e.id or e.classList
    else return false;
  }
}

document.onkeypress = stopRKey;
```

```html
<input type="text">

<textarea></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here an another solution:

```js
var textAreas=document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
   for(var i=0;i<textAreas.length;i++){
       textAreas[i].onkeypress=stopRKey;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm on mobile so not tested but this should work

```
document.addEventListener('keypress', e => {
    If(document.querySelector(':focus').type !== 'textarea' && e.keyCode == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 document.onkeypress = function(evt) {
 if(evt.target.toString() !== '[object HTMLTextAreaElement]' && evt.charCode === 13){
  evt.preventDefault();
  return;
 }
};
```